dynamoose/nestjs querying with value in an array
I have a DynamoDB table with the following schema:
import { Schema } from "dynamoose/dist/Schema";

export const ObjectSchema = new Schema ({
  id: {
    type: String,
    hashKey: true,
  },
  values: {
    type: Array,
    schema: [String],
  }
});

I want to select all items where the values array contains a specific string.
I tried the following approaches:
.scan().where('values').contains(value) 

and
.scan('values').contains(value)

However, both attempts result in the error:
TypeError: node.forEach is not a function
Here’s the method that I'm using:
  async findByValue(
    value: string,
  ): Promise<ExampleObject[]> {
    return await this.objectModel
      .scan('values')
      .contains(value)
      .exec();

Is there a way to query all items with the specific value in the values array, without retrieving all the items in the client and filtering them manually?
